# Logging a Table and Appending other text data to a .csv file in Python

Tags: python, bash, csv, logging

I am trying to add the datas I obtained to a .csv file.
Horizontally it will be like;

```
TimeStamp-NMEA(GGA)-F1000a-NUIMWireless-CONF-........

TimeStamp2-NEMA(GGA2)-other access points in the other location
.
.
.
Simply I want to log all the access points in a file by using a Python loop.


~ $ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | python iwlistparse.py

Name           Address             Quality   Channel   Encryption

F1000a         FC:F5:28:B0:29:CB    50 %     4         WPA v.1

NUIMWireless   00:26:99:4D:0D:31    26 %     11        Open

CONF           00:26:99:4D:0D:30    25 %     11        WPA v.1

OPAC           00:26:99:4D:0D:33    25 %     11        WPA v.1

eduroam        00:26:99:4D:0D:35    24 %     11        WPA v.1

STAFF          00:26:99:4D:0D:34    22 %     11        WPA2

STAFF          00:26:99:4D:0F:34    20 %     1         WPA2

NUIMWireless   00:26:99:4D:0F:31    19 %     1         Open

eduroam        00:26:99:4D:0F:35    17 %     1         WPA v.1

CONF           00:26:99:4D:0F:30    17 %     1         WPA v.1

OPAC           00:26:99:4D:0F:33    17 %     1         WPA v.1
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question needs rewriting, but if the data is horizontally as given in the first part of your question, I would suggest the use of `cut`:

```
cut -d- -f3 your_input
```

This takes the third field from a file where the separator is `-`.

And if the data is given "vertically" as in the output of your script, simply take the first field:

```
awk 'NF { print $1 }' your_input
```

which simply prints the first field of all non-empty lines.

Comment: Thank you, and do you know if there is a good tutorial for parsing, I am pretty new in Python and the bash.

Comment: There are galore! Just Google it! :)